# Regex javascript for Minimum 8 characters,at least one number and one special character, maximum 32 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex that check "Minimum 8 characters at least one number and one special character, maximum 32 characters." , My regex is :

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,16}$
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Did you just copy/paste that regex from somewhere?

Comment: yes, the special chars is not executed. it only validate 8-32 chars and at least one number, how ?

Comment: I want must at least  contain special chars, not may ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I test this regex can work satisfied

```
/(?=^.{8,32}$)(?=(?:.*?\d){1})(?=.*[a-z])(?=(?:.*?[!@#$%*()_+^&}{:;?.]){1})(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%*()_+^&]*$/
```

you can watch the live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/tuxrM/

```
var re = new RegExp(/(?=^.{8,32}$)(?=(?:.*?\d){1})(?=.*[a-z])(?=(?:.*?[!@#$%*()_+^&}{:;?.]){1})(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%*()_+^&]*$/);

var test1 = '1234567',      //  less than 8 characters
    test2 = 'aaaaaaaa',     //  no  number & no special character
    test3 = 'aaaaaaa1',     //  no special character
    test4 = 'aaaAaa#1',     //  satisfied
    test5 = 'abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890332123';  //  more than 32 characters

re.test(test1);     //  FALSE
re.test(test2);     //  FALSE
re.test(test3);     //  FALSE
re.test(test4);     //  TRUE
re.test(test5);     //  FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually best solved by 3 different regular expressions.

```
/[0-9]/ //Check for at least one number.
/(SPECIAL CHARACTER)/ //Check for at least one special character. Please define "special" character.
```

And then

```
str.length >= 8 && str.length <= 32
```

If this is a password, *do not* limit your users in password length.