# angular validating match password using view

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to implement a form validation using only the view - i'm trying to avoid creating a new directive for this.

Question - is possible to validate matching password only using the partial/view e.g:

```
div(ng-class="{true: 'no-match'}[password != password2]")
```

any tip will be gladly appreciated :)

Comment: anyway i could validate password2 w/o been ng-modal? I need to validate the form but not pass the value of password2 on submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible ,

```
<input name="password" ng-class = "{valid: (password1 == password2),
                    invalid: (password1 != password2) }" ng-pattern="/[0-9]/">
```

where, valid and invalid are css classes,

to display an error message regarding that, use

```
<div id="invalidEmail" class="mismatch"
    ng-show="testForm.password.$error.pattern && !testForm.password.$pristine">
    Please enter atleast a number
</div>
```

where testForm is your form name like

```
<form name="testForm"> </form>
```

For more reference you can see the link  http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html

Comment: anyway i could validate password2 w/o been ng-modal? I need to validate the form but not pass the value of password2 on submit

Comment: in your controller code, in the submit function delete password2 from formdata , using `delete $scope.formdata.password2;`

Comment: what if i want the password to contain at least a number?

Comment: then simple use a regex as pattern

Comment: I think this will do  `.*[0-9].*`, you can get more help here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543972/regex-javascript-for-minimum-8-characters-at-least-one-number-and-one-special-ch    and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342626/regular-expression-for-at-least-one-number

Comment: I have edited the answer , i think it will be helpful